# Modify css of text field or select in vuetify components

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to modify the css of the vuetify components for example change the `font-size` to `10px`, but it does not take my class into account 
Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640047/1981247) relevant? Or can you provide more info?

Answer (score 5):

I'm gonna assume you are using one of the pre-processors out there (SASS or Stylus). 
So the thing is that you probably have the style section **`scoped`** for example `<style lang="scss" scoped>`.

What you want to do, is to use the **deep** selector so the styles from your parent component will leak into the child component, in this case **vuetify** component.

That can be achieved in sass like so:

```
<template>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
         <v-btn color="success">Success</v-btn>
    </div>
<template>
```

And then in the style tag:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .button-wrapper /deep/ button{
        background: #00e389;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
```

- **Note**: I do not use Stylus but if I'm not mistaken the syntax for deep is `>>>` so in this case, it will be `.button-wrapper >>> button`. you can read more about it [here in the vue-loader docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your component:

```
<!-- in your component -->
<template>
  <p class="change-font">Changing font</p>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  };
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
  .change-font{
    font-size: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

If you are using stylus, scss, or something else, change `lang="css"` to `lang="stylus"` or `lang="scss"`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stylus, you can do it :

```
<style lang="stylus" scoped>
.wrapper >>> button
    font-size 10px
</style>
```